# Is AssemblyInfo required in UWP apps?

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm not using reflection to get assembly properties/attributes, and I don't care about the "properties" dialog for my assemblies since it's a packaged UWP app obtained via the Store anyway.

Can I delete every `AssemblyInfo.cs` file? Or could it cause problems?

Comment: All elements in AssemblyInfo are metadata. No metadata is `required` but they are `recommended`

Comment: I'm mostly wondering whether there's any tooling (e.g. VS) that could be confused by the lack of metadata like version numbers.

Comment: You'll need those meta data if you start to develop and operate huge applications. For a 10h app; nobody cares.

Comment: What important metadata for "huge applications" are you thinking of?

Comment: Version and FileVersion